# Target a printer using chrome extension's printerProvider listeners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I want one page of my website to print on printerA, and another page on printerB. I don't want to force user to keep switching between printers.

I am trying to add chrome extension which uses printerProvider listeners.

I receive event onGetPrintersRequested. And I return random printer. I want to know how can I know the ID of the printer before hand?

code:

```js
chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(
    function ( resultCallback ) {
        resultCallback( [{
      id: 'printer-id-here', // printer address
      name: 'My Printer',
   description: 'super printer'
    }] );
    }
);
```